# Azure AD User and attribute export

Tags: database, ldap, azure-active-directory, integration, user-accounts

I'm working with a third party application and I need to get a copy of the user directory from a clients Azure AD. I've searched the docs/google and had trouble finding a simple automated solution for syncing the user database.

Is there any way I can user LDAP to import a copy of the users to a third party solution, similarly to how it is done with on-premise AD?

Answer (score 1):

"I need to get a copy of the user directory from a client's Azure AD" - if you want to import users from Azure, unfortunately user writeback is not currently supported. You can upvote the feature request below. The feature was removed back in 2015.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/16887037-enable-user-writeback-to-on-premise-ad-from-azure

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-preview